# Error with adaptor.fill

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Here is my c#

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

public partial class _Update : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void UpdateAccount(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE_ACCOUNT_DETAILS", myConn))  
        using (DataSet dsBank = new DataSet())


        {

            string commandSql = "SELECT * FROM CARDHOLDER_ACCOUNT_DETAILS WHERE CARD_NUMBER = " + txt_CurrCardNumber;
            string bankId = null;
            string name = null;
            string address = null;
            string cardNumber = null;
            string balance = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(commandSql, myConn);
            SqlDataAdapter myAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand2);

            {

                myConn.Open();
                myAdaptor.Fill(dsBank);

                bankId = dsBank.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BANK_ID"].ToString();
                name = dsBank.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NAME"].ToString();
                address = dsBank.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ADDRESS1"].ToString();
                cardNumber = dsBank.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CARD_NUMBER"].ToString();
                balance = dsBank.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BALANCE"].ToString();
                string NewBankIdInsert = null;

                if (int.Parse(txt_NewBankId.Text) > 5 || int.Parse(txt_NewBankId.Text) < 1)
                {
                    NewBankIdInsert = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    NewBankIdInsert = txt_NewBankId.Text;
                }

                if (txt_CurrBankId.Text != bankId || txt_CurrName.Text != name || txt_CurrCardNumber.Text != cardNumber || txt_CurrAddress.Text != address)
                {
                    txt_AccountMade.Text = "We could not update your account, check if you have inserted incorrect details.";

                }

                else
                {

                    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    if (NewBankIdInsert == "")
                    {
                        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@NEW_BANK_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 999999;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@NEW_BANK_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(NewBankIdInsert);
                    }
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@NEW_CARD_NUMBER", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_NewCardNumber;
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@NEW_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_NewName;
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@NEW_ADDRESS1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_NewAddress;
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OLD_CARD_NUMBER", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cardNumber;

                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    int New_balance = rnd.Next(1000, 10000);

                    if (New_balance == int.Parse(balance))
                    {
                        New_balance += 1000;
                        if (New_balance > 10000)
                        {
                            New_balance -= 2000;
                        }
                    }
                    if (txt_NewCardNumber.Text != cardNumber && txt_NewBankId.Text != bankId)
                    {

                        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@NEW_BALANCE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = New_balance;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@NEW_BALANCE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(balance);
                    }


                }
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                txt_AccountMade.Text = "Your account details have been changed.";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my html

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Update_Account.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Update" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD/ XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtmll/DTD/xhtmll-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Bank Management</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1 style="font-size:125%;">Insert Your Details Below</h1>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <h1 style="font-size:80%;">Bank-Id</h1>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_CurrBankId" runat="server" Width="380px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <h1 style="font-size:80%;">Card Number</h1>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_CurrCardNumber" runat="server" Width="380px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <h1 style="font-size:80%;">Name</h1>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_CurrName" runat="server" Width="380px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <h1 style="font-size:80%;">Address</h1>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_CurrAddress" runat="server" Width="380px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
         <h1 style="font-size:125%;">Insert Your Details Below</h1>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <h1 style="font-size:80%;">Bank-Id</h1>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_NewBankId" runat="server" Width="380px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <h1 style="font-size:80%;">Card Number</h1>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_NewCardNumber" runat="server" Width="380px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <h1 style="font-size:80%;">Name</h1>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_NewName" runat="server" Width="380px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <h1 style="font-size:80%;">Address</h1>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_NewAddress" runat="server" Width="380px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_Invoke" runat="server" Width="380px" OnClick="UpdateAccount" Text="Finish" stlyle=":;" />
        <br />
        <asp:Textbox ID="txt_AccountMade" runat="server" Width ="380px"

ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>  
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the error on my myAdaptor.Fill(dsBank) 
I am getting the error

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The multi-part identifier "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox" could not be bound.

(end of error)
I have a piece of code of which is basically this but without the html (is a web service) and I essentially copy/pasted it, changed some variables and that works, so I don't understand why this does not.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Oh, also, this is not exactly relevant to my post, but in my html, how do I make it so that my text boxes are side by side? (so I want my 'currCardnumber' etc to be next to 'newcardnumber')

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be `txt_CurrCardNumber.Text`

Comment: Ok well now I am getting the same error but with my nonQuery

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Procedure or function 'UPDATE_ACCOUNT_DETAILS' expects parameter '@NEW_BANK_ID', which was not supplied.

Comment: It was a statement, not a question, updated anyway as it _is_ the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question about the text boxes you can use css to style your textbox like this:

```
textbox {
    display: inline-block
}
```

Comment: I don't do html its just that I've been told to do this with my webpage (learning c#)

Comment: An easy option is an internal style sheet. Otherwise you can make a seperate .CSS file and add a link to it inside your head tag.

But for the internal style sheet Inside your head tag insert a style tag like this:

 <head><style>
    TextBox {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>

Comment: I'm not sure how that will work with your asp:TextBox elements. You may want to give each of them a class like this:

<asp:TextBox ID="txt_CurrAddress" class="textbox" runat="server" Width="380px"></asp:TextBox>

And then reference the class in your CSS like this:

.textbox {display:inline-block}

Answer (score -1):

### **Try this code below it may work**

### **Sql Query String**

> string commandSql = "SELECT * FROM CARDHOLDER_ACCOUNT_DETAILS WHERE
> CARD_NUMBER = " + txt_CurrCardNumber;

### **Using SqlDataAdapter**

> SqlDataAdapter myAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(commandSql,myConn);
>
> myAdaptor.Fill(dsBank);

### **Using SqlCommand**

> SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(commandSql, myConn);
>
> myConn.open();
>
> myCommand2.ExecuteNonquery();
>
> myCommand2.Fill(dsBank);
>
> myConn.Close();

Comment: yeah I fixed the 'myAdaptor.fill' bug but now its my nonquery that doesn't work